# How to reduce inventory when creating a purchase instance in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, inventory

I'm working on a Django project that is a simple restaurant management system. One of the key functionalities is to record inventory and purchases. I'm looking to add functionality where once I create a Purchase instance, my program automatically reduces the inventory by the amount used in that purchase.

I've been scratching my head a bit and poking around the internet but I'm honestly not sure exactly where to start. This is my first Django project so would greatly appreciate a bit of direction.

See below for my models.py and views.py.

Models.py

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
    ingredient_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    units_avail = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ingredient_name + " avail: " + str(self.units_avail)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/inventory"

class MenuItem(models.Model):
    menu_item_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.menu_item_name + " with Price: " + str(self.price)

    def available(self):
        return all(recipe_req.enough() for recipe_req in self.reciperequirement_set.all())

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/menu"
    
    def cost(self):
        item_cost = 0
        for recipe_req in self.reciperequirement_set.all():
            item_cost += recipe_req.ingredient.price
        return item_cost
    
    def profit(self):
        item_cost = self.cost()
        item_profit = self.price - item_cost
        return item_profit

class RecipeRequirement(models.Model):
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Inventory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    menu_item = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ingredient.ingredient_name + " in " + self.menu_item.menu_item_name

    def enough(self):
        return self.quantity <= self.ingredient.units_avail

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/recipe"

class Purchase(models.Model):
    menu_item = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.menu_item.menu_item_name + " at " + self.timestamp
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/purchase"
```

Views.py

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, "index.html")

class InventoryListView(ListView):
    template_name = "inventory.html"
    model = Inventory
    context_object_name = "inventory_list"

class MenuListView(ListView):
    template_name = "menu.html"
    model = MenuItem
    context_object_name = "menu_list"

class InventoryUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Inventory
    template_name = "inventory_update.html"
    form_class = InventoryUpdateForm
    context_object_name = "inventory_update"

class InventoryCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Inventory
    template_name = "inventory_create.html"
    form_class = InventoryCreateForm
    context_object_name = "inventory_create"

class MenuItemCreateView(CreateView):
    model = MenuItem
    template_name = "menu_create.html"
    form_class = MenuItemCreateForm
    context_object_name = "menu_create"

class RecipeRequirementListView(ListView):
    template_name = "recipe.html"
    model = RecipeRequirement
    context_object_name = "recipe_list"

class RecipeRequirementCreateView(CreateView):
    model = RecipeRequirement
    template_name = "recipe_create.html"
    form_class = RecipeCreateForm
    context_object_name = "recipe_create"

class PurchaseListView(ListView):
    template_name = "purchase.html"
    model = Purchase
    context_object_name = "purchase_list"

class PurchaseCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Purchase
    template_name = "purchase_create.html"
    form_class = PurchaseCreateForm
    context_object_name = "purchase_create"
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you make a purchase, you will have purchase quantity, right?
Put this query after the Creating the Purchase object and store your purchased_qty in a variable.

```
from django.db.models import F

purchased_qty = 10   #Example
Inventory.objects.filter(ingredient_name='xyz').update(units_avail=F("units_avail") - int(purchased_qty))
```

This will do minus purchased qty from your `Available qty` from `Inventory`. But I'm not sure about the Relationship between Inventory and Purchase. I guess you're comparing Product Names as a Character field.
I hope this will help you.

Comment: this is helpful. thank you. i will explore this approach